# C - Compile static file

Tags: c, build, compilation, shared-libraries

I want to compile C code into one monolithic executable file (include every dependencies in this file) using GCC. 
Usually I can compile the code with this command:

```
gcc -o server ex-serv-x509.c  -lgnutls
```

But when I try to compile it with this -static argument I get this error:

```
[root@localhost test]# gcc -static -o server ex-serv-x509.c  -lgnutls
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[root@localhost test]#
```

How I can solve the problem?

Best wishes

Comment: The best way to build a static executable involves traveling back in time to 1986.

Comment: Do you have a libc.a somewhere?

Comment: Would you give some more information?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Static executables still have their uses. If you don't find a libc.a on your system, this is most likely the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `ldd` command to see what it's linking in without the `-static` option.  Here's what I get for a silly program I have.

```
~$ gcc so.o -lm -o so
~$ ldd so
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00db7000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00c7f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0037f000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x002da000)
~$ gcc so.o -static -lm -o so
~$ ldd so
    not a dynamic executable
```

So without the static I automagically get the shared version of libc, which surprised me even though it should not have.  I imagine you have the shared version but not the static, so you'll need to get the static library from somewhere if you have decided that 1986 is the year for you :-).

To make sure you can do: `gcc -print-search-dirs` and search through them and make sure that libc.a is not to be found.